# Color entries of an index

Tags: makeindex

`Makeindex` with option-s `*.ist` does not print the indexes. What do options=`* mean`? Is any command that allows me to colour the entries of the index? I use `TexWorks` with `Miktex`.
Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=one,title=Index One, intoc, options= -s one.ist]
%\makeindex[name=one,title=Index One, intoc]
\makeindex[name=four,title=Index Four, intoc, options= -s four.ist]
%\makeindex[name=four,title=Index Four]
\makeindex[name=six,title=Index Six, intoc, options= -s six.ist]
%\makeindex[name=six,title=Index Six]

\usepackage[hangindent=0pt,subindent=0pt,subsubindent=0pt]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!2:2}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!5:5}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!3:3}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!5:5}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!6:6}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!7:7}
\index[one]{Acts of the Avocados!8:8}
\index[one]{Romaines!3:3}
\index[one]{Romaines!4:4}
\index[one]{Romaines!5:5}
\index[four]{Aristotle!Metaphysalis!205c}
\index[four]{Aristotle!Metaphysalis!306d}
\index[four]{Plato!Tomatoes!407e}
\index[four]{Cicero!Lettuce!115}
\index[six]{Bananerges}
\index[six]{Appleadorus}
\index[six]{Plato}
\index[six]{Plato!\textit{Potatoes}!144a}
\index[six]{Plato!\textit{Potatoes}!166d}

\printindex[one]
\printindex[four]
\idxlayout{itemlayout=abshang} 
\printindex[six]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you supply files `one.ist`, `four.ist` and `six.ist`? Because that's what you are telling `makeindex` to use to style your indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`options=-s XXX.ist` tells `makeindex` to use the index style specified in `XXX.ist`. Unless this is a standard file, you need to supply it. If you don't mean to specify tailored styles for each index, just drop this from the options. The indexes are then created just fine.

```
\makeindex[name=one,title=Index One, intoc]%, options= -s one.ist]% or supply style in file one.ist
\makeindex[name=four,title=Index Four, intoc]%, options= -s four.ist]
\makeindex[name=six,title=Index Six, intoc]%, options= -s six.ist]
```

Comment: I create three files with *.ist extension with window editor and can't get the output.

Comment: @HoudaAraj Well, what is in those files? You need to include their content in your question.

Comment: These are the content of the three files.one.ist
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1

four.ist
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1

six.ist
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1

Comment: @HoudaAraj You need to add that information to your question since the problem doesn't occur without those files.